# How to compile jar/artifact and dynamically load it without stopping the server in debug mode (Maven project)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have Spring Boot server which build from different modules, now starting the server takes a lot of time. Currently when I'm doing change I need to stop the server, `cd` to the module directory run `mvn clean install`, and then in the IDE pressing the debug button to start the server so it will reload the new compiled module.

My question is is there any way to compile and load the module without stopping the server from within the IDE? It's not Spring or other framework question, it is general IDE specific.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools

Comment: i dont understand how it can help ... sorry @Boris the Spider

Comment: This instruction describes how to use Spring dev tools in IntelliJ IDEA: https://faun.pub/10-steps-to-enabling-auto-reload-for-spring-boot-in-intellij-230326413b68

Comment: my question now is specific to spring but it is general question
i update my question